# OpenShift Origin on Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, openshift-origin

I have problem to deploy OpenShift Origin on Fedora 19. I'm getting error:

```
Preflight check: verifying system and resource availability.

Checking broker.example.com:
* SSH connection succeeded
* Target host is running non-Fedora, non-RHEL
* Located getenforce
* SELinux is running in please login as the user "fedora" rather than
the user "root". mode
* Located yum
* Located puppet
* Located augtool
* Located dnssec-keygen
* Located htpasswd
* Located scl
* ERROR: The ruby193 software collection is not installed. Correct
this by running `yum install ruby193` on this system.
* ERROR: The 'epel' repository isn't available via yum. Install /
enable this repository and try again.
```

That's weird:

```
Target host is running non-Fedora, non-RHEL
```

Release:

```
[root@broker tmp]# cat /etc/issue
Fedora release 19 (Schrödinger’s Cat)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
```

I'm not able to install ruby193 via yum. Dependency problem. Fedora 19 has ruby version 2.0.0. Log from installation of ruby193: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TpJEF4Rw

So I'm using rvm:

```
[root@broker tmp]# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24 revision 45159) [x86_64-linux]
[root@broker tmp]#
```

At the end, I'm installing Origin by:

```
sh <(curl -s https://install.openshift.com/)
```

And my configuration file: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sSgYVVMt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that problem was in ssh check. I was not able to ssh to broker but installation script was facing as if ssh is OK.

Needed packages: (yum -y install) ruby unzip httpd-tools puppet augeas bind

<strike>Interesting. I solved it by adding repos and install some things:</strike>

```
cat <<EOF> /etc/yum.repos.d/openshift-origin-deps.repo
[openshift-origin-deps]
name=openshift-origin-deps
baseurl=http://mirror.openshift.com/pub/origin-server/release/3/fedora-19/dependencies/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOF

cat <<EOF> /etc/yum.repos.d/openshift-origin.repo
[openshift-origin]
name=openshift-origin
baseurl=http://mirror.openshift.com/pub/origin-server/release/3/fedora-19/packages/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOF

yum clean all
yum -y update

yum -y install ruby unzip httpd-tools puppet bind vim rubygem-openshift-origin-container-selinux</strike>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would email this to the openshift origin users list here (https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo/users) alot of the developers are on that list and should be able to help you with a solution. Then once you have one come back here and update us so that if anyone else runs into it they'll have something to reference.